# how to run this script in cron.d every minute?

Tags: bash, cron

i am using ubuntu 15.04 i got huge ddos attacks i wanted to stop that attacks by blocking attackers ips so i am planing to run this script every minute inside cron.d and make it automatically start

how can i do that

```
#!/bin/bash

#Collecting list of ip addresses connected to port 20000

netstat -plan|grep :20000|awk {'print $5'}|cut -d: -f 1|sort|uniq -c|sort -nk 1 > /root/iplist

#Limit the no of connections
LIMIT=10;

for ip in `cat /root/iplist |awk '{print $2}'`;do

if [ `grep $ip /root/iplist | awk '{print $1}'` -gt $LIMIT ]
then
echo "100 connection from $ip... `grep $ip /root/iplist | awk '{print $1}'` number of connections... Blocking $ip";

#Blocking the ip ...

/etc/rc.d/init.d/iptables save > /dev/null;
CHECK_IF_LOCALIP=0;
/sbin/ifconfig | grep $ip > /dev/null;
if [ $? -ne $CHECK_IF_LOCALIP ]
then
{
FLAG=0;
grep $ip /etc/sysconfig/iptables | grep DROP > /dev/null;
if [ $? -ne $FLAG ]
then
iptables -I INPUT -s $ip -j DROP;
else
echo " Ipaddress $ip is already blocked ";
fi
}
else
echo " Sorry, the ip $ip cannot be blocked since this is a local ip of the server ";
fi
fi
done
```

Comment: Just an FYI: DDoS attacks work by actively attacking and flooding the network pipe, for the most part.  Blocking at the firewall won't save you from the network pipe being flooded - if I am blocked by your firewall, the traffic is still reaching your box (only to be dropped by the firewall) so the DDoS isn't mitigated in this way.

Comment: but those attacks comming  when i manually block them they couldn't attack any more

Comment: It doesn't prevent them from reaching the box through the pipe, it just drops the traffic after it reaches your box and is processed by the firewall on the system; it has still gone over your uplink to the Internet and reached your box which is why your firewall will see the traffic, but also why this won't be effective as they are still flooding your uplink. DDoS mitigation has to be done upstream of your box by the provider of the Internet service. An iptables firewall at the endpoint where your system is connected to the Internet will not mitigate DDoS.

Comment: Related to this, is a question/answer combo on the INformation Security Stack Exchange, which covers a similar question of how to mitigate DDoS via the firewall on a server: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/what-is-a-good-public-available-iptables-script-for-ddos-mitigation  (TL,DR: You can't).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing on the `cron` entry rather than the content of the script, assuming the script is `~/foobar.sh`, to run the script every minute as `cron` job, open your `cron` table by `crontab -e` and add:

```
*/1 * * * * ~/foobar.sh
```

Make sure the script is executable at first.

`*/1` in the minute column will make `crond` to execute the script every minute, while if you put just `1` the script will be executed only on the first minute of the given hour(s).

Comment: i am doing */1 * * * * /root/ipblock/ddoschecker.sh i dont know if this correct

Comment: @Vlark.Lopin This is correct, just make sure the script is executable.

Comment: yes its start store  ips in iplist finally it worked thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To add an entry to `crontab`, use `sudo crontab -e` and then will open an editor (probably vi or the program will let you choose). Then add the task following the structure: `minute hour (day of month) month (day of week) command`. Use number values or * to express 'any' of it. Every job in one line. And then, save it.

In your case will be something like `*/1 * * * * /full/path/to/the/script.sh`

See [this page](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucrontab.htm), could help you to fully understand how works crontab and cronjob.

Comment: lets say i put it in root folder so i do like this `1 * * * * /root/path` ?

Comment: also i added this line after #// comment

Comment: Yes, the line would be correct. Remember you must put the full path to the script, and the script must have execution permission. Hope this works, after all.

Comment: i put the sh in the root directory on folder called ipblock/script.sh , so i added 1 * * * * /root/ipblock/script.sh

Comment: This is incorrect, `1 * * * * /full/path/to/the/script.sh` will make `crond` to run the script only on the first minute of every hour, not every minute..

Comment: @melchor629 Its not fair when a [correct answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/808572/216503) has been put already in the meantime

Comment: @heemayl I'm sorry, but the answer was (I see that now no) selected as the good one and I didn't want to be incorrect